# How to prevent triggering button event when press 'enter' key and hold?

Tags: javascript, html

Case are show blow:

If you click the button and then press 'enter' key and hold for it, the button's click event will trigger constantly.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  console.log(1);
})
```

```html
<button>press Enter</button>
```

There's no jQuery, no form, no input. I wonder how this work and how to prevent it...

Thanks for you.

Answer (score 3):

It happens because pressing Enter on a button triggers its click event, and when you hold a key, key repeat kicks in and keeps "typing" that key over and over.

If you want to ignore the event for a period of time after it's been triggered once, you can add code to your handler to do that:

```js
var IGNORE_TIME = 1000; // One second
var lastClick = null;
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  var now = Date.now();
  if (!lastClick || now - lastClick > IGNORE_TIME) {
    lastClick = now;
    console.log(1);
  }
});
```

```html
<button>press Enter</button>
```

If you **never** want pressing Enter on the button to "click" it (which I don't recommend, you may make it difficult for someone with a disability who relies on using the keyboard), you can prevent the `keydown` event on the button:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  console.log(1);
});
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  var key = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
  if (key == 13) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<button>press Enter</button>
```

See also [vlaz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52576839/157247), which only prevents the keypress if it's from key repeat, which seems like an excellent compromise.

Comment: Can we fully destroy the enter event ?

Comment: @SudhirOjha - We can hook the `keydown` event on the button and prevent it. I'll add that.

Comment: For the record, with a keyboard event, you can also just look at [`event.repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/repeat) which will tell you if the key was held down.

Comment: @vlaz - To my mind, that would make a good answer to this question. Let me know if you post it. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder OK, I did now. I actually started writing that before there were any answers but I had to go away from the PC for a bit. When I came back, there were already three answers, and I would just add a comment.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the fact that when you click the button. the button keep the focus state

Answer (score 1):

**Revised answer:** When a key is held down, the sequence of events you would expect to get is `keydown` -> `keypress` -> `keydown` -> `keypress` -> (... same two events repeated ...) -> `keyup`. Knowing that, you can keep track of what was pressed in `keydown` and know that it finally ended in a `keyup`.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  console.log(1);
});

var keysCurrentlyPressed = {};

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  var key = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
  if (keysCurrentlyPressed[key]) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  } else { //this is the first time the key is pressed, add an entry for this key
    keysCurrentlyPressed[key] = true;
  }
});

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
  var key = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
  delete keysCurrentlyPressed[key]; //note that the key isn't pressed any more
});
```

```html
<button>press Enter</button>
```

This will work on any environment that is DOM Level 3 compliant, so all major browsers. However, [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#Auto-repeat_handling) some older environments would treat a key pressed down as repeatedly pressing the key, sending `keydown` -> `keypress` -> `keyup` each time. If that's the case, you can use [T.J. Crowder's solution which uses a timeout period](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52576558/3689450).

If using ES6, you can store the pressed keys in [a Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and you can wrap the whole thing in a closure, to prevent the keys from being available to other code that probably doesn't need them.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  console.log(1);
});

(function() {
  const keysCurrentlyPressed = new Set();

  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('keydown', e => {
    const key = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
    if (keysCurrentlyPressed.has(key)) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      keysCurrentlyPressed.add(key);
    }
  });

  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('keyup', e => keysCurrentlyPressed.delete(e.keyCode || e.charCode));

})()
```

```html
<button>press Enter</button>
```

**Original answer:** You can prevent a key being held down by looking at the [`Event.repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/repeat) property. However, the `repeat` property is not supported on Edge or Internet Explorer, so this will only work on Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  console.log(1);
});

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  if (e.repeat) { //don't do anything if a key is held down.
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<button>press Enter</button>
```

If you clock the button and hold down Enter or even Space, you won't get repeated events.

Worth noting - you need to add a listener for a keyboard event (`keydown`, `keypress`, or `keyup`) to use the `repeat` property. The `click` is a mouse event which doesn't have a `repeat`, as it makes no sense for it.

Comment: Side note: `return false` does nothing at all in an `addEventListener` callback. See my blog post [*The true story on `return false`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/11/story-on-return-false.html). :-)

Comment: I know that, but I added it as a shorthand to stop repeating the `keyboard pressed` message. Upon reflection I suppose I didn't need either of these. Good link, by the way :)

Comment: So, I revised my answer, because I realised the `repeat` property doesn't work on IE and Edge. Which I find a bit bizarre but there you go. Apparently it was part of the spec at one point but then it wasn't, which is probably why Microsoft dropped it.

Comment: Another small update. Apparently [`repeat` *is* in the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#events-keyboardevents). So, I don't know why Microsoft don't support it. Probably because it's Microsoft.

Comment: Definitely a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

As the button has focus, every event (as is pressing Enter) is directed to that button and executed. To prevent it from happening multiple times, you can remove the focus by using `blur()`. It then executes only once, untill the user sets focus on the button again.

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', 
  function (e) {
    console.log(1);
    this.blur();
})
```

Comment: But when i use vue/react, it's not so recommend to use native event object... And another question is I already have so many use in my project, can i have some simple way to resolve so many button event?