# Why 'onkeydown' callback is fired before 'onclick'?

Tags: javascript

There is the following code:

```html
<div onkeydown="console.log('onKeyDown')">
<button onclick="console.log('onClick')">Test onClick</button>
</div>
```

If I tab to the button and press Enter I'll see 2 messages: 'onKeyDown' at first and 'onClick' at second. Why does 'onkeydown' event fire before 'onclick' event? I thought that 'onclick' event must bubble firstly.

Comment: why is mousedown before click

Comment: `keydown`, as the name suggests, fires when you press down the key. `click`, here being triggered by a **Return** key press, fires when the action completes, i.e. when the key is released. So it cannot work in any other order since time only moves in one direction.

Comment: Also, if you're wondering `keyup` happens before `click`, too.

Comment: Also, how could I cancel onclick event from onkeydown?

Comment: I don't think you can. At best, you can keep some shared state that both handlers can access and flip `isAllowedToRun` (or whatever) to `false` at `keydown` and then look for it at `click` time.

Comment: You can try to stop the propagation of events, but I doubt it will work because they are different events. But still, you can try it. But what exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to detect when a button is clicked or a key pressed to do something to handle the form sending? If so, use the `onsubmit` event on the `<form>`.

Comment: This may be relevant: [How to prevent triggering button event when press 'enter' key and hold?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52576489/how-to-prevent-triggering-button-event-when-press-enter-key-and-hold/)

Comment: _"Also, how could I cancel onclick event from onkeydown?"_ — if you figure out a way to prevent button push by the enter (or space) key, _**Please Don't Do It**_ … you will be impairing keyboard accessibility for users with disabilities, or just for people (like me) who do a lot of navigation and "clicking" using the Tab and Space on the keyboard. This harms overall usability.

Answer (score 0):

Click is considered a "KeyPressed" event - keydown and keyup event completed - by JavaScript. Thus when you "begin" to click - by depressing the mouse button, for instance, the onkeydown event will trigger, before the click is released, at which point an onKeyUp event will be registered, and the two events taken together will also trigger an onKeyPressed event.

So browsers will register and process onKeyDown before waiting for the key to be released, at which point an onKeyUp event will be registered and processed.

See https://www.mutuallyhuman.com/blog/keydown-is-the-only-keyboard-event-we-need/ if this explanation is unclear.

Comment: https://imgur.com/OpONRdO <-- That is not true for Google Chrome 77.0.3865.90 running on Linux Mint 19.1. (the keydown there was the key combination to take a screenshot, when I click on the button and then hold CTRL+SHIFT)

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel interesting. I seem to recall Linux issuing some different order of events around keydown/keyup/keypress/click and I think this might be one of them.

Comment: @VLAZ Probably, but *I* don't see anything different in this example.